# Проверка на повторение события у календаря

Tags: android, дата, события, calendar

У класса Event есть две переменных startTime и endTime типа Date. На основе этих переменных заполняются события в календаре. Необходимо сделать проверку, которая бы предотвращала и уведомляла пользователя о том, что созданная им запись не входила в промежуток других. Мне бы только принцип понять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нарисовать временную прямую и расположить на ней 2 события понять будет проще

```
for (Event event : events) {
    if (event.startTime.getTime() > newEvent.endTime.getTime() && event.endTime.getTime() > newEvent.startTime.getTime()) {
        System.out.println("Даты пересекаются");
    }
}
```

Где `events` - уже существующие события, `newEvent` - новое событие